# Filter object by child array in ng-repeat statement that uses track by $index to handle dupes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an object `narrow.searchedMenu` with 3 equal-length child arrays, which I display using `ng-repeat` with `track by $index` because there are some duplicate elements.

```
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in narrow.searchedMenu.description track by $index">
         {{ narrow.searchedMenu.name[$index] }},
         {{ narrow.searchedMenu.short_name[$index] }},
         {{ narrow.searchedMenu.description[$index] }}</li>
  </ul>
```

I need to be able to filter the displayed results by keeping only those results where a keyword appears in the `description`. If a `description` doesn't match I want to exlcude the `name` and `short_name` as well as the `description`.

Normally I would use something like this:

```
| filter{description:'chicken'}
```

appended to the end of the `ng-repeat` statement. However, it does not seem to work with `track by`.

It gives me this error on the console when I try it:

> Error: [$parse:syntax]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$parse/syntax?p0=%7B&p1=is%20an%20unexpected%20token&p2=16&p3=NaNndex%20%7C%filter%7Bdescription%3A'chicken'%7D&p4=%7Bdescription%3A'chicken'%7D

I've tried several other potential solutions but so far no luck.

Note that the `$scope` is not injected into my controller and if I try using a custom filter I get the following error:

> "Error: [filter:notarray]
>   errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/filter/notarray?p0=0";

One last thing -- I'm told to avoid `includes` because of it not being supported widely enough (someone said something about `polyfill` being an alternative, but I'm not sure if it's applicable to this?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom filter attached to an object in your controller, **as long as you put `track by` as the last statement** in `ng-repeat`.

The filter in your controller would look like this:

```
menu.chickenFilter = function(item) {
  return (item.indexOf('chicken') > -1)
}
```

The `ng-repeat` would become:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in narrow.searchedMenu.description | filter: narrow.chickenFilter  track by $index">
         {{ narrow.searchedMenu.name[$index] }},
         {{ narrow.searchedMenu.short_name[$index] }},
         {{ narrow.searchedMenu.description[$index] }}</li>
```

Comment: Thanks. Good point. I think I tried this but had a problem because the $scope isn't injected into my controller. Let me give it a try really quickly. Update: OK yea, that seems to be the problem, it gives me `ReferenceError: $scope is not defined`. Hmm I just tried injecting the $scope into the controller but it still gives that error. I'm not sure if that's because I'm working with promises and/or using controller as syntax. Does it have to be on the $scope?

Comment: OK so, I put that filter in another object and I think it can "see" it now, but it's giving me another error I encountered with some earlier attempts: "Error: [filter:notarray] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/filter/notarray?p0=0"

Comment: Thanks. The code snippet is awesome (and I put it in my Evernote), but I still get the error mentioned. Some of the differences between the snippet and mine is that I don't have the `$scope` and more importantly mine is an object with 3 child arrays whereas this is just an array... or at least I *assume* that's the problem because of the error message saying "notarray"? I'm not sure...

Comment: In order for you to access the array in the template, you'll need to bind it to scope. And it needs to be an _array_ for ng-repeat _or_ filter to work. So that's correct. yes.

Comment: Why don't you make sure it's an array :)

Comment: The children are arrays and they work with `ng-repeat` (I'm just trying to filter a list that otherwise looks good). I don't know what the message is talking about, unless it means that `searchedMenu` is an object instead of an array. I tried injecting `$scope` but it didn't help and I was taught not to explicitly inject it in a controller that's using promises. I can access the `chickenFilter` without scope but it's just giving me that error.

Comment: Well anyway, while this doesn't work for me I'm going to upvote it for the effort and helpfulness, but please let me know if you have any further thoughts

Comment: I got it to work!! If you update your answer I can give you credit. This post led to the solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31509769/filter-notarray-error-in-angularjs  I just had to 1. attach the filter to an object in my controller (`menu`) then 2. re-arrange your solution to put "track by" last. Also I added the alias of the controller to the filter. I've updated your question, feel free to edit it further if you like. Thanks!

Comment: Great! Ah the track by was my bad. The alias shouldn't have an effect on the logic though.

Answer (score 0):

Go with this

```
 <ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in narrow.searchedMenu track by $index" ng-if="narrow.searchedMenu[$index].description.indexOf('chicken')>-1">
     {{ narrow.searchedMenu.name[$index] }},
     {{ narrow.searchedMenu.short_name[$index] }},
     {{ narrow.searchedMenu.description[$index] }}</li>
</ul>
```

I have created a plunker here

http://plnkr.co/edit/KXvD4JgwRe9wNszt8rCy?p=preview

Comment: That looks promising! I got this console error tho `Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$parse/syntax?p0=-&p1=is%20an%20unexpected%20token&p2=12&p3=NaNndex%20%7C%20ng-if%3D&p4=-if%3D`

Comment: you can check the plunkr its working fine and it is a clean solution. You need to debug your code and i think there would be some silly mistake

Comment: There were some differences in your plnkr from what's in my question. When I make your plnkr like the code in the question it doesn't work. http://plnkr.co/edit/xBE21b0yhhgI6mhFz3wL?p=preview Also even the solution in your original plunkr didn't match the desired result I described...

Comment: can you paste the json data for which you are trying to apply  ng-repeat